# How to load utility methods dynamically in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, next.js, dynamic-loading

Doy you think it is wort to sort out logic to utility files and load dynamically to speed up site?

I have a `getInvoiceDetails` method in `getInvoiceDetails.tsx` file:

```js
export default const getInvoiceDetails = (
  eventId: string
) => {
```

I import it in an other file, in a component:

```js
const getInvoiceDetails = dynamic(
  () => import("../../Utility/BuyTicket/getInvoiceDetails")
);
```

and call it:

```js
let resp = getInvoiceDetails(
      eventId
```

But `yarn build` raise an error:

```
  Not all constituents of type 'ComponentType<{}>' are callable.
    Type 'ComponentClass<{}, any>' has no call signatures.

  286 |   const callInvoiceDetails = () => {
  287 |     callSaveData();

> 288 |     let resp = getInvoiceDetails(
> Blockquote
```

Do you know what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Next.js dynamic import is used to dynamically import *React components*.

Here you are trying to import a utility function - you can simply use the regular [ES2020 dynamic import](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import) instead.

```js
const getInvoiceDetails = await import("../../Utility/BuyTicket/getInvoiceDetails");
```

Comment: compiler says: `./pages/buyTicket/[eventId].tsx:27:9
Type error: Property 'getInvoiceDetails' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/Users/kukodajanos/Workspace/Ticket/Portal/Utility/BuyTicket/getInvoiceDetails")'.`

Comment: Ah yes, it's actually a default export not a named one. I've updated my answer.

Comment: now I got this, sorry, `./pages/buyTicket/[eventId].tsx:27:27
Type error: Top-level 'await' expressions are only allowed when the 'module' option is set to 'esnext' or 'system', and the 'target' option is set to 'es2017' or higher.`

Comment: That's because you're trying to use the `await` at the top level. You can either change your `tsconfig` as the error message suggests, or use the dynamic import within a function.